# Is there an issue with "select" function in " tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm using tidyverse package and select function as follow:

```
df %>%
  select(Adapt_ID, Age, BMIall) %>%
  view()
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the following error message

```
Error in select(., Adapt_ID, Age, BMIall) : unused arguments (Adapt_ID, Age, BMIall)
```

I suspect that the select function might exist in other packages so I use the following:

```
df %>%
  tidy:: select(Adapt_ID, Age, BMIall) %>%
  view()
```

I got the same error message.

I'm not sure what is the issue. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 2):

This is most probably due to the fact that you have another package (probably `MASS`) with the same function name. `select` is from `dplyr` so you can use -

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% dplyr::select(Adapt_ID, Age, BMIall) %>% view()
```

Comment: This has **got** to be a duplicate ...

Comment: That's true. I just noticed that the question was asked before in the forum. unfortunately, I cant delete the question!